# Redundant column to maintain data integrity

Tags: postgresql, database-design, referential-integrity

Consider the following example:

```
Syllabus
-id 
-course_id 
FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES Course(id)   

SyllabusItem 
-id
-syllabus_id 
FOREIGN KEY (syllabus_id) REFERENCES Syllabus(id)   

Course 
-id   

Class 
-id 
-course_id 
-syllabus_item_id 
-syllabus_id <--- redundant column 
FOREIGN KEY (course_id, syllabus_id) REFERENCES Syllabus (course_id, id)
FOREIGN KEY (syllabus_item_id, syllabus_id) REFERENCES SyllabusItem (id, syllabus_id)
```

The second foreign key constraint is used to ensure the `Syllabus Item` belongs to the `Syllabus`, which belongs to the `Course` the `Class` belongs to. But in order to maintain this relationship, we have to add a redundant column `syllabus_id` to `Class`.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve data integrity in this example?

Comment: I would remove syllabus_item_id from Class. Class could join with Syllabus, and Syllabus join to SyllabusItem. This would be third-normal form (3NF), which is conventional design for transactional DBs. A de-normalized version would be to combine Syllabus and SyllabusItem. This is often used in data warehouses.

Comment: If `SyllabusItem` applies to `Class` directly, I would remove `syllabus_id` from `Class`. You could add a trigger to check that the `syllabus_id` for your `SyllabusItem` matches the `syllabus_id` for your `Course`..